# Evolving Avro Schema where the Record Name changes and using alias for it does not work

Tags: java, spring-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

So I have one avro schema Which I want to evolve and using topicRecordName strategy. I am using confluent schema registry. I want to have it backward compatible and It is necessary that I change the Record Name.
Old schema

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "OldSchema",
  "namespace": "com.example.kafkaschemaregistrydemo.event",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "firstName",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

New Schema

````
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "NewSchema",
  "aliases": ["OldSchema"],
  "namespace": "com.example.kafkaschemaregistrydemo.event",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "firstName",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}```
I am using `KafkaAvroDeserialiser` in java to deserialize.
````

The way I am comsuming the message is as Follows

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "TopicName", groupId = "test-group")
    public void consume(@Payload NewSchema event){
        System.out.println("Supplier New Event");
        System.out.println("Consumed message" + event.toString());
    }
```

Error that I face

```
Cannot convert from [com.example.kafkaschemaregistrydemo.events.OldSchema] to [com.example.kafkaschemaregistrydemo.event.NewSchema] for GenericMessage....
```

The reason why I want to have change record name because I have two Schemas which I wanted to merged into one single event while maintaining Backward Compatibilty.

Few Things that I tried
I assumed that having the alias should have being enough especially when having aliases for other fields works fine but not for RecordName.

1. changing
   `configProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, false);`
2. Having the old schema be also be generated along with new Schema
3. tried with both `SpecificRecord` and `GenericRecord`
4. Tried without `@Payload`
5. When I check the backward Compatibility it passes.
   Is it even possible and if not what options do I have ?

Answer (score 0):

When the compatibility between two schemas is checked and the names don't match, then the aliases are checked. However, they are compared to the **full** name of the writer schema's record.

Try to change your alias to `com.example.kafkaschemaregistrydemo.event.OldSchema` and see if that works.